# How can you mock HttpResponse<String>

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am trying to create some unit tests using the java.net.http.HttpClient API. The code works fine but I am getting **org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue** error when running the unit tests.

```java
      @Mock
      HttpResponse<String> mockResponse;
    
      @Spy
      HttpClient httpClient;

      @Test
      void callExternalApi_success(){
         when(mockResponse.body()).thenReturn("Testing body");
         // ERROR ON THE LINE BELOW:
         when(httpClient.send(any(), any(HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString().getClass())))
                    .thenReturn(mockResponse);
         String url ="http://testing-url";
         String externalApi = openPagesExternalApi.callExternalApi(url);
         assertEquals(externalApi, "Testing body");
      }

      callExternalApi(String url){
         HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().uri(new URI(url)).build();
         HttpResponse<String> send = conn.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
         return send.body();
      }
```

**Error in Console**
HttpResponse$MockitoMock$35694822 cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:

1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies -

   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

Comment: Show the original code that you are trying to test. On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: @pvpkiran I have highlighted the line on which I'm getting the error.

Comment: please paste the stacktrace of the error

Comment: Should the second parameter be `eq(String.class)`?

Comment: @knittl yes the second parameter is String

Comment: @HarmeetKaur if you agree, then why do you use different code? Also, have you read bullet point 2 of the error message?